# Add up value using database field value with savefield in cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp

my question is pretty simple but hard to find an answer for though search engines.

I simply want to update a field in the database, using that fields old value to add another value. I'm using the following at the moment:

```
$this->Advertisement->saveField('total_views', '(total_views + 1)', false);
```

But this gives me the next query:

```
UPDATE `advertisement` SET `total_views` = '(total_views +1)', `modified` = '2011-08-26 10:44:58' WHERE `advertisement`.`id` = 16
```

This is wrong and it should be:

```
UPDATE `advertisement` SET `total_views` = (total_views +1), `modified` = '2011-08-26 10:44:58' WHERE `advertisement`.`id` = 16
```

The problem is where it puts `(total_views +1)` between quotes.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->Advertisement->updateAll(
array('Advertisement.total_views' => 'Advertisement.total_views + 1'),
array('Advertisement.id' => 1)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else gets stuck with this, the spaces in the query are important.

**works**: `Advertisement.total_views + 1`

**does not work**: `Advertisement.total_views+1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Advertisement->updateAll(array('Advertisement.total_views'=>'Advertisement.total_views+1'), array('Advertisement.id'=>$id));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that for a similar issue I was able to resolve it in the following manner,

```
$this->Advertisement->updateAll(
array('Advertisement.total_views = Advertisement.total_views + 1'),
array('Advertisement.id' => 1)
);
```