# Incrementing Cakephp database field by a value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have this field whose value i have to increment the field value by a specific value.
I am using this

```
$data['quantity']     = 'Order.quantity+1';
```

which doesnt works for me quantity is a integer coloumn here.
Also will it work when nothing is in database?.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: You can check below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202256/add-up-value-using-database-field-value-with-savefield-in-cakephp/7202882#7202882

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use updateAll() for this

a little googling reveals this pretty quick:
http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Auto-Increment-A-Field-td3491697.html

Comment: i'm afraid that's not possible since updateAll and deleteAll are the only atomic methods and therefore the only ones which can use those string field name references.

Comment: I have to correct my previous comment: deleteAll() is also not atomic in CakePHP 2.x. Only updateAll() is.

Answer (score 16):

I used updateAll in my code to increment views in an article. Therefore, every time an article is visited, I call the following function from within my view action in my articles controller:

```
function incrementViewCount($id) {
    $this->updateAll(
        array('Article.viewed' => 'Article.viewed+1'),                    
        array('Article.id' => $id)
    );
}
```

Then in your controller…

```
$this->MyModel->incrementViewCount(123);
```

Basically similar to the tutorial suggested in the previous answer.

Comment: In fact this is invalid (at least it does not work for me) and i had to do something like this:         return $this->updateAll(
            ["hits_count" => $this->query()->newExpr("hits_count+1")],
            ["id IN" => $ids]
        );

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code also. Works fine for simple ++/-- operations without the need of additional querying.

https://gist.github.com/denchev/8209318

Answer (score 1):

Using saveField:

```
<?php

$this->Article->id = $id;
$this->Article->saveField('viewed', (int)$this->Article->field('viewed') + 1);

?>
```

Comment: this makes way more queries and needed - also, atomatic queries as stated above will always increment correctly... yours might not.

Comment: Yep, not claiming it's efficient. :)  Could you cast the the value returned from the field call to an integer to ensure the increment? (edit made in code)

Comment: The problem is that it's non-atomic, so another process can increment the 'viewed' field while this one is incrementing.. Losing one increment in the process.