# adding integers to mysql field with cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incrementing Cakephp database field by a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689203/incrementing-cakephp-database-field-by-a-value)

I want to add an integer to an existing int in my database (not another column, literally mathematically add a number to an existing value).

Say I have a table entries

```
id | Entry | total
```

If I wanted to add 1 to the total of a specific entry can I do something like this?

```
$this->Entry->find($id);
$this->Entry->saveField('total' + 1, true);
```

I also tried adding this to a function in EntriesController but it didn't work

```
$this->Entry->updateAll(array('Entry.total'=>'Entry.total+1'),array('Entry.id' => $id));
```

Here's another way I tried to do this

```
//in the controller
$this->Entry->increaseOne($id);

//function in the model called by the controller
public function increaseOne($id){
    $this->Entry->updateAll(array('Entry.total'=>'Entry.total+1'),array('Entry.id' => $id));
}
```

**edit - I got it to work**

Comment: have you tried something like that? What is the outcome??

Comment: Nothing happened. The value remained the same in my entries table

Comment: Then you should re-word your question.

Comment: @rlemon I tried what they suggested but but didn't have much success. I updated to show what I did.

Comment: What's the query that's generated? Add `echo $this->element('sql_dump');` in your layout

Comment: @tigrang good call with the sql_dump. I realized it wasn't querying from the right model. My mistake!