# Using CakePHP's set()/save() functions, how can I save a value based on an increment of an existing value?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am happy with CakePHP's cleansing functions that allow for safe insertion using the save/set model functions. I currently need to save the increment of an existing model's data and cannot work out the required process.

Currently my model's code reads as:

```
$this->save(array('Model.field', 'Model.field + 1'));
```

But I have noticed that, as expected, this will not work as the entire string is escaped, rather than an integer increment for the field in question. Any help is much appreciated.

I am aware that a workaround would be to first query the row in question, and then increment the value in PHP, but I would prefer to use a solely MySQL/query solution.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689203/incrementing-cakephp-database-field-by-a-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Model::updateAll(). You will find examples in the manual.

Comment: Thanks but I do not need to update multiple rows, which is what the updateAll function appears to do. I need to update a single row with a field based on an increment of it's existing field (an integer) in the database.

Comment: @rhys: you are wrong about that. updateAll is for atomatic queries which may contain above increment updates. So it is also suitable for single-row-updates.

Comment: Thanks mark, I stand corrected. I will look further into this.

Comment: Not the first time I hear this. Reading the manual is so overrated.

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this:

```
$this->id = 1;
$data = $this->read();
$this->saveField('field_name', $data['Model']['field_name'] + 1);
```

Alternatively, you can use query();

```
$this->query('UPDATE Model.field_name = Model.field_name + 1 WHERE Model.id=1');
```