# Increment last inserted value CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I need to generate a unique value for a column. I want to increment the last inserted value in the table.

I've tried this, but to no avail

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $code = $this->Department->find('first', array(
        'fields' => 'Department.code',
        'order'  => 'Department.code DESC'
    ));
    $code += 1;
    $this->data['Department']['code'] = $code;
    if($this->Department->save($this->request->data)){
        $this->Session->setFlash('New department added.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saving **$this->request->data** but you put your data in **$this->data**.

Try with this:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $code = $this->Department->find('first', array('fields' => 'Department.code','order' => 'Department.code DESC'));
    $code += 1;
    $this->request->data['Department']['code'] = $code;
    if($this->Department->save($this->request->data)){
        $this->Session->setFlash('New department added.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also just use the atomic updateAll() to do everything in a single and fast query - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689203/incrementing-cakephp-database-field-by-a-value.

Answer (score 0):

$id = $this->User->getLastInsertId ();

by this function you will get last inserted id and now increment its value and use it where you want to use or ncrement this id and save it in your database