# cakePHP update table fields

Tags: mysql, cakephp, sql-update, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakePHP problem - I want to make a update query like this

`UPDATE table SET field = field + some_var`

and I don't know how to do it...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

The only "right" way would be using cake's "atomic query" wrapper methods. In your case that would be "updateAll".
The question is a complete duplicate of a dozen other questions - like [Incrementing Cakephp database field by a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689203/incrementing-cakephp-database-field-by-a-value)

```
$var = 1;
$this->Article->updateAll(
    array('Article.viewed' => 'Article.viewed + ' . $var),                    
    array('Article.id' => $id)
);
```

This is also in the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do an update:

If you are only updating one field you can do:

```
$this->Model->id = foo;
$this->Model->saveField('field_name', 'field_value');
```

or, you can do an update using $this->Model->save():

```
$data = array(
    'Model'=>array(
        'id'=>foo,
        'field_name'=>'field_value',
        'another_field_name'=>'another_field_value'
    )
);

$this->Model->save($data);
```

You want to avoid using $this->Model->query() and use CakePHP's built in methods because the build in methods are datasource agnostic (they work the same on MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback method beforeSave to implement what you need.

[Callback Method: BeforeSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave)

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!empty($this->data['table']['field'])){
         $this->data['table']['field'] += $this->data['table']['some_var'];
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Although this has the effect of adding the two values together it does not account for the fact that there might be two overlapping actions. As an example, if you make two deposits at nearly the same time, one for $10 and one for $100, only the last one to commit would get applied. The original query would capture both since it does not rely on data in the model to compute the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Using $this->query("UPDATE table SET field = field + some_var") is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is using the `Model::updateAll(array $fields, array $conditions)`.

The `Model::saveField(string $fieldName, string $fieldValue, $validate = false)` this method  when you try to update using same primary key it shows `cannot replace duplicate key error`. And  think when one updates they must be using the primary key as a matching value to update value.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->Baker->updateAll(
    array('Baker.approved' => 'Baker.approved + ' . $some_var),
    array('Baker.id' => $someId)
);
```

For more information see: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html